# How do I type curly quotes in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, insert, macros, quotes, symbols

I am actually posting this question in order to provide an answer to the world, because I could not find the solution explicitly when I searched Google for a long time.

I wanted to be able to type curly quotes (“” ‘’) in NetBeans quickly because I edit a lot of essay files, but I couldn't find any sort of "smart quote" option that converted ugly-quotes to pretty-quotes in appropriate situations. Please correct me if such a technique exists. My solution involved macros.

I ended up creating macros that are simple enough that I'm not stressed by them. I can type `ctrl + '` for a single left quote and `alt + shift + "` for a double right quote, etc. I included all of my macros in my answer.

Peace homies.

Answer (score 0):

The macros that satisfied me are as follows:

```
ctrl + ' = "‘" //Named Single Left
alt + ' = "’" //Named Single Right
ctrl + shift + ' = "“" //Named Double Left
alt + shift + ' = "”" //Named Double Right
```

Note: The macro is straight quotes around each kind of curly quote. This was logical to me because alt corresponds to the right quotes, and ctrl to the left quotes. The shift action is identical to ordinary word-processor situations.